# All in one OPEN SOURCE ADSL2+ Wireless Router?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, open-source, firmware, adsl2+

Is there any **all in one** solution for an ADSL2+ Modem + Wireless Router with an open source  (Linux, or any of the BSD guys) firmware I can hack into and configure at my pleasure?

I've been googling for about an hour without any success so far.

### UPDATE

I actually ended up choosing a cheap [Linksys WAG120N](http://home.cisco.com/it-eu/products/gateways/WAG120N) wireless router+adsl2 from CISCO. It costed me a little above 40 EUR.

Although it appears it has an open source firmware (based on Linux, I gather) [whose source code can be directly downloaded from their website](http://homesupport.cisco.com/it-eu/gplcodecenter?gplsku=#WAG120N), I think I will bind a *plug computer* to it, or some other tiny solutions (read the comments for the informative links).

Comment: I'm sure you started by searching for replacement firmware for your specific device... but we'd need the make and model to be able to do the same.

Comment: Actually, no. I just would like to find any model of any manufacturer with an open source firmware. I am not trying to replace my current router/modem firmware.

Comment: Not sure how reliable this is, and it is an old post: http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1178166  Here is some mention of using RouterOS for what you are describing: http://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=26685

Comment: I updated the post, I couldn't add more links in it, here they are.

1) Plug computers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug_computer.
2) Various small PC's with Linux and similar: http://raymii.org/cms/p_Small_Linux_PCs_overview

Comment: Wny wasn't the update posted as an answer then accepted as the answer?

Comment: Because I already accepted izzy's one as the answer... and because I haven't thought of accepting my own decision as an aswer, to be honest.

Hope I did nothing too bad. :)

Comment: Btw, did you downvote me, or...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buffalo WBMR-HP-G300H: it is the first modem router working with DD-WRT:
http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/content/first-adsl-router-with-dd-wrt-support

Answer (score 1):

Interpreting your question as a search for suitable hardware having open-source firmware available (and not a search for open-source firmware for some router you already own) -- I'd say there are some. I own a [Fritz!Box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fritzbox) from AVM, and there is an open source project called [Freetz](http://freetz.org/) providing an extended firmware you can build on your own with the features *you* want (they provide an "appliance" VM, so it shouldn't be a big deal). I'm pretty happy with my "Freetz-Box".

Ah, btw: Yes, it's running on Linux...

Comment: Btw: if you have an Android device, there are a bunch of apps available to remote-control that box :)

Comment: I did not end up buying that one, but I will accept your answer nonetheless. :)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @FabioA. thank you -- so it looks like it at least pointed you to the right direction :) And for me (plus other curious readers), please: What did you end up with? Might be helpful for others as well.

Comment: I actually ended up choosing a cheap [Linksys WAG120N](http://home.cisco.com/it-eu/products/gateways/WAG120N) wireless router+adsl2 from CISCO. It costed me a little above 40 EUR. 

Although it appears it has an open source firmware (based on Linux, I gather) whose source code [can be directly downloaded from their website](http://homesupport.cisco.com/it-eu/gplcodecenter?gplsku=#WAG120N), I think I will bind a [plug computer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug_computer) to it, or [some other tiny solutions](http://raymii.org/cms/p_Small_Linux_PCs_overview).

I will update the question.